# Paragraph border appear blurry inside FlowDocument, both SnapsToDevicePixels and UseLayoutRounding are not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

When I use `BorderThickness` Property to draw a border on a `Paragraph` element inside `FlowDocument` in `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`, the border appear to be **blurry** sometimes.

Here is my code snippet.

```
<Grid>
    <FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.5">This is a paragraph</Paragraph>
            <Paragraph BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.5">This is a paragraph</Paragraph>
            <Paragraph BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.5">This is a paragraph</Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I have tried to put `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` and `UseLayoutRounding="True"` on both the `Grid` or `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` (since the `Paragraph` itself doesn't support these properties), but nothing happen.

Is this problem still an issue? if not, How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Grid RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased">
        <FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph Margin="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".5">This is a paragraph</Paragraph>
                <Paragraph Margin="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".5">This is a paragraph</Paragraph>
                <Paragraph Margin="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".5">This is a paragraph</Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: +1 thanks @HighCore, adding the `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"` in my case is working. But when I put your code, some of the border lines vanished. This is still an unresolved issue :D

Comment: @RwinzCyruz the problem is that you're setting the `Borderthickness` to a value below 1, which when rounded (in order to "SnapToDevicePixels") is rounded to 0.